# CKEditor5 get length of text only

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

I'm using CKEditor5 for a comment form, and want to impose a character limit. My current implementation is to count the length of string given by `editor.getData()`. However, I am allowing images to be embedded in the comment form and using the base64 upload adapter, which contributes to this character count.

Is there a way to only count the number of characters from non-image related characters?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you checked https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/word-count.html ?

Comment: Ah. That seems like a better way to do it. Thanks!